# How to create fixed header within css grid

Tags: css

How can I keep the css grid template for a fixed header? When I add position: fixed; to my header div the elements within dont stay in their positions

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MLwBpW

```
.container {
 display: grid;
 margin: 20px;
 }

 #header {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 grid-column-start: 1;
 }

 h1 {
 font-size: 2em;
 margin: 0; 
 }

 h2 {
 margin: 5px; 
 grid-column-start: 2;
 grid-column-end: 3;
 }

 p{
 grid-column-start: 3;
 grid-column-end: 3;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 width: 600px;
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack!. Which part you want to make it as a header in your code

Comment: The header is taken out of the document flow so `grid-row:1` collapses to zero height. You'd have to specificy the height of `grid-row:1` or calculate it with Javascript and apply *that* height. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/exNxKX